# SQL Where and Like in PHP imploded string

Tags: sql, postgresql, implode

I have text field in my pgsql DB which contains users identificators. One field can contain one or more ids separated by #. On saving numbers are imploded using PHP, so I can have for example:

```
Row 1: 3#36#66#33

Row 2: 5#56#33#55.
```

How should I prepare SQL query to select field with one or more ids without any ambiguity?

Example:

```
SELECT product FROM cms_product WHERE product_mod LIKE '3'
```

Both row 1 and 2 can be selected which I don't want. How I can fix it?

**EDIT:**

I will have to select all rows that contains user ID in this filed, for example:

```
UserId: 3
Field 1:
55#64#333#2
Field 2:
12#3#55#6423
Field 3;
654#33#11#98
```

Only field 2 should be selected.

Comment: "first there was database normalization.... aaaaaaand it's gone" (reference: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/and-its-gone)

Comment: On a more serious note, though, columns that contains multiple, char-separated values are a sign of "code smell" or otherwise a bad schema design, usually. I don't know if postgresql has special tools for these, but from your query I said it does not or at least you're not using them.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear to me. What exactly do you want to do? You want to search for "3" but do not want to find rows that contain "364" or "33"? In any case. Your DB-Design is messed up, you're not paying attention to normalization. You should never ever store a comma (or any other char) seperated list of anything. Ever! Seriously check out Database normalization. That'll make your problem go away by itself - check this out: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/

Comment: I see now. I'm projecting this table now and I thought about doing this that way... I will consider your tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should **really** work to normalize your DB this is the answer to the posted question

```
select product
from cms_product
where '3' = any(regexp_split_to_array(product_mod, '#'))
```

Comment: Yep I will definitely normalize it, but I hope your advice is it so +1.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for before I decited to normalize DB.